# How do you set felica card touch as an event trigger using tkinter with python

Tags: python, tkinter, nfc

I'm new to python/tkinter. I have been trying to create a program...

- with a tkinter UI with some radio buttons
- that reads felica IDm through a reader (Pasori) set on a PC
- when a card is placed on the reader, it shows the felica IDm of the card and the selected radio button on the tkinter UI

Without the tkinter UI and just using prompt, I'm able to get the felica IDm of the placed card, but when trying to add a UI to my program, it hasn't been working right. Nothing happens even if a card is placed on the reader.

This is my program for now:

```
#felica card reader
import nfc
#hash
import hashlib
import binascii
#UI
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
#time
import time

#main window
main_win = tkinter.Tk()
main_win.title("card and button info")
main_win.geometry("800x500")

#main frame
main_frm = ttk.Frame(main_win)
main_frm.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tkinter.NSEW, padx=5, pady=10)

#font style
#title
fontStyle_title = tkFont.Font(size=30)
#options
fontStyle_options = tkFont.Font(size=20)

#explanation label
explanation_label = ttk.Label(main_frm, text="Select button from below and touch your card", font=fontStyle_title)

#number 0 will be selected
var = tkinter.IntVar()
var.set(0)
rdo_options = ['option A','option B','option C']
color_options = ['light blue', 'orange', 'light gray']
#radio buttons
for i in range(len(rdo_options)):
    rdo = tkinter.Radiobutton(main_win, value=i, variable=var,
                              text=rdo_options[i], indicatoron=0,
                              width=20, padx=20,
                              background='white', activebackground=color_options[i], selectcolor=color_options[i],
                              font=fontStyle_options)
    rdo.place(x=200, y=100+i*60)
   
#widgets
explanation_label.place(x=10, y=0)

#configure
main_win.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
main_win.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
main_frm.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

#felica reader
clf = nfc.ContactlessFrontend('usb')
print(clf)

#waiting for a card to be placed
while True:
   
    print('waiting...')
   
    #get tag and IDm
    tag = clf.connect(rdwr={'on-connect': lambda tag: False})
    idm = binascii.hexlify(tag.idm)
   
    #selected radio button
    selectedButton = rdo_options[var.get()]
    print('selected button:')
    print(selectedButton)
   
    #convert idm using hash
    idm_converteddata = str(binascii.hexlify(idm), 'utf-8')
    hashvalue_felicaIDm = hashlib.sha224(idm_converteddata.encode()).hexdigest()
   
    explanation_label['text'] = hashvalue_felicaIDm, " placed with button ", selectedButton, " selected."
    
    print(hashvalue_felicaIDm, ' placed with button ',  selectedButton,  ' selected.')
       
    #wait for 1.5 sec
    time.sleep(1.5)
   
    #go back to waiting
    explanation_label = ttk.Label(main_frm, text="Select button from below and place your card", font=fontStyle_title)
   

main_win.mainloop()
```

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The while loop blocks the execution of tkinter `mainloop()`. You need to execute the while loop in a threaded function.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply, and thank you for the advice! I will try improving my script. Thanks so much. 